# MongoDB refuses Connection on Windows 10 machine

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, database-connection

i'm running a Node.js app on my Windows 10 machine. I have Mongoose installed and setup like this:

```
// Init Database
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var mongoDB = "mongodb://127.0.0.1/sampledata"
mongoose.connect(mongoDB);
var db = mongoose.connection;
// Check DB connection
db.once("open", function(){
    console.log("Connected to MongoDB");
});
// Check for DB errors
db.on("error", function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

Now, when I start the server with `nodemon`, the following error appears in the console:

```
{ MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]
  at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:564:11)
  at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
  at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
  at Connection.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:317:12)
  at Connection.g (events.js:291:16)
  at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
  at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\...\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:246:50)
  at Socket.g (events.js:291:16)
  at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
  at emitErrorNT (net.js:1278:8)
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ]
}
```

When I try to start mongo over the console, I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin>mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-10-03T19:05:24.194+0200 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Es konnte keine Verbindung hergestellt werden, da der Zielcomputer die Verbindung verweigerte (in english: A connection couldn't be established, because the target computer has refused the connection). :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I've never encountered this error before and as stupid as it sounds, yesterday everything worked fine. Haven't changed the code or anything, so it must be an issue with my computer I guess.
Do you guys know what could cause this error?

Comment: Have you started mongo on ur system.?

Comment: I tried to, but I cannot get connection. I updated the question with the corresponding console output

Comment: are you sure mongodb is running on the system try running 
mongod --dbpath="yourdbpathhere"

Comment: it worked perfectly fine until today. running `mongid --dbpath="..."` resulted in an infinite wait for the connection to open

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Start mongod server

```
mongod
```

Open another terminal window

Start mongo shell

```
mongo
```

**Longer Version:**

Open Command prompt as an administrator and run `netstat -anb`, check which port mongodb is listening to (Usually 27017). If you dont see a listing for mongo then it means that mongod is not running, so go ahead and start mongod.exe  from the mongodb binaries(or if environment variables are set, run `mongod` from anywhere on your cmd).

if this doesnt work, your firewall is probably blocking access on that port, so check that out

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error as well. In my case, I was trying to upgrade to MongoDB 4.0 without first upgrading to 3.6.
Please see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.0/#upgrade-procedures if you recently updated MongoDB.